# How do I join multiple tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

I am new to SQL Joins and finding it tough to logically join more than two tables. I have a table called `PastExperience`

```
PastExperience(id,eembossline,embossname,pastexperience,insertiondate,userid,dateofstay)
```

and I am joining it with my `Users` table using `UserID` to map both tables

```
Users(UserName,MerchantID,Userid)
```

To achieve this I wrote following query which works fine

```
Select
Convert(varchar(50),PE.dateofstay,103) 'Date of Stay',PE.embossname 'EmbossName', PE.pastexperience,U.UserName from PastExperience PE
inner join Users U
on U.UserId=PE.userid
where embossline='3100041810000001'
```

Now what Im trying and struggling with is, I want to select MerchantName1 from my Merchant table too on a particular `EmbossLine`

```
Merchant(MerchantID,MerchantName1)
```

`EmbossLine` with `MerchantID` can be mapped from `card` table

```
Card(MerchantID,EmbossLine,EmbossName)
```

How can I join these multiple tables?
I tried something like this but my syntax is wrong

```
Select
    Convert(varchar(50),PE.dateofstay,103) 'Date of Stay',
    C.embossname 'EmbossName',
    PE.pastexperience,
    U.UserName ,
    M.merchantname1 
    from PastExperience PE 
    inner join Users U on U.UserId=PE.userid
    inner join Card C on C.MerchantID = Merchant.MerchantID
    where PE.embossline='3100041810000001'
```

Comment: which table has  embossline column?

Comment: Please avoid using images to describe your table structure. Instead, use DDL statements or simply list the columns of every table in text. This is hardly readable as it is now.

Comment: How does Card table or Merchant Table relate to either `users` or `PastExpierance` tables?

Comment: Post has been Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get the desired result. This is my query

```
Select
    Convert(varchar(50),PE.dateofstay,103) 'Date of Stay',
    C.embossname 'EmbossName',
    PE.pastexperience,
    U.UserName ,
    M.merchantname1 
    from card C 
    inner join PastExperience PE on c.EmbossLine=PE.embossline 
    inner join Users U on U.UserId=PE.userid
    inner join Merchant M on M.MerchantID=C.MerchantID
    where PE.embossline='0093000110000001'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Convert(char(10),PE.dateofstay,103) 'Date of Stay',
       PE.embossname 'EmbossName', 
       PE.pastexperience,
       U.UserName,
       M.MerchantName1
from PastExperience PE
inner join Users U on U.UserId=PE.userid
inner join Cards C on (PE.EmbossLine = C.EmbossLine)
inner join Merchant M on(U.MerchantId = M.MerchantId AND C.MerchantID = Merchant.MerchantID)
where embossline='3100041810000001'
```

**Note #1:** Code was written directly here, there might be some mistakes.
**Note #2:** I've changed your target data type of the convert from varchar(50) to char(10), string the convert function will always return a fixed length string.

Comment: U have missed out Card table in join

Comment: To my understanding the Card table is irrelevant since none of it's columns is in the select or where clause.

Comment: @Zohar Your query shows two different `MerchantName` in the result set, but in the table this particular `EmbossLine` has transaction only against one `Merchant`

Comment: @Nuke If you want a better answer, please edit your question and make it more readable as I've already asked you in a comment to your question. My eyesight is 20/20 but in order to read the column names of your table I had to zoom in to 150%.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
 Select
    Convert(varchar(50),PE.dateofstay,103) 'Date of Stay',
    PE.embossname 'EmbossName',
    PE.pastexperience,
    U.UserName ,
    M.merchantname1 
    from PastExperience PE
    inner join Users U on U.UserId=PE.userid
    inner join merchant m on m.merchantid=u.merchantid
    inner join card C on m.merchantid=C.merchantid and PE.EmbossLine = C.EmbossLine
    where embossline='3100041810000001'
```

Comment: Your code is duplicating results with respect to `Users`